# How can I write an ast.NodeTransformer to convert a=1 to a function call a=variables("a")?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

The python docs and greentreesnakes show it's possible to use `ast.NodeTransformer` to change python code via ASTs:

I want to change assignments like `a=1` to `a=variables(1)`.

I'm getting a bit confused over what `ctx` is and when it's needed, the output of astor doesn't seem to have it, yet it seems to be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not necessarily need the `NodeTransformer` to do this. If you already have the `AST` and know the node (an `Assign` node in this case) you can modify in-place as below.

```
import ast

src = 'a = 1'
code = 'variables(1)'

tree = ast.parse(src)
assign_node = tree.body[0]
assign_node.value = ast.parse(code).body[0].value
```

The updated `AST` can be used further for whatever is your purpose. For example, you can generate the source code back (using say the `astor` module as `astor.to_source(tree)` in the above example). `NodeTransformer` is handy if you need to find the node given some condition. It has a similar `visit_*` functions like `NodeVisitor` that allows you to do this in place. Like below:

```
from ast import parse, NodeTransformer

class ChangeAssignment(NodeTransformer):
    
    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        if assign_node.targets[0].id == 'a':
            node.value = parse('variables(1)').body[0].value
            
        return node

src = 'a = 1'            

t = ChangeAssignment()
tree = parse(src)
tree = t.visit(tree)
```

The `ctx` for variable determines if it is for loading, storing or deleting a variable. It is required if you create the node directly (above I use `parse` to create nodes implicitly). For modifying the `AST` or generating the source back (like `astor.to_source`) it does not matter what the `ctx` you use. If you, however, directly pass the `AST` to Python `compile` function, it will complain if the correct `ctx` is not used.

Comment: I had been passing the code to `compile` which explains the complaining :)
`dump` from greentreesnakes *does* include `ctx`, after switching to the ast it generates I can use it in NodeTrandformer with minimal changes.


Using `parse` like this looks more readable, but I guess there is a small performance penalty?


As a middle-ground I might use the AST, with source in a docstring with unittest to ensure they match.

Comment: Yes parse will add to performance. Also if you are directly using it to `compile`, use the `fix_missing_locations` for it to work.